# Implement Apple Sign in button for different language in app RTL

Tags: ios, swift, arabic, apple-sign-in, rtl-language

My app has 2 languages English And Arabic which the user chooses when he enters the app for the first time. I do not use the device locale.

In the case of RTL language, I also have to change the text "Continue with Apple" to Arabic manually and also shift the apple logo to the right of the text.

Refer to the image

[image: login screen showing sign in with apple button]

Comment: Your problem is that the button follows the device locale.  Rather than providing the user with a language choice when they launch your app, why not just use standard localisation and have the app present English or Arabic based on the device locale.  That way the Apple button will be automatically localised.

Comment: I have used this library to achieve the same and change the language without closing the app - https://github.com/cmaftuleac/BundleLocalization

Comment: iOS 13 now allows users to select a specific language for an app in the app settings.   You are probably better off relying on that and not using that library.

Comment: And what should I use for the previous version of iOS? @Paulw11

Comment: Either nothing or you could use the library if you detect an iOS before 13; there is no Sign In with Apple prior to iOS 13 so the button won’t be an issue

Comment: I made a custom button. An exact replica of the button apple provides. My app has been accepted in the app store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in for an almost imposible task my friend , as far as of my knowledge and also whats listed here https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple/overview/

only way that you can alter the button name is by changing the locale to what ever you want it to be, in otherwords when you change the device language the button text will change. While you can change the button width , height and background color the image positioning is questionable but i am not knowledgable enough to comment on the image positioning. However it seems that the button positoning is default and the only way the text will change through is the locale.Refer to the link above it contains everything u need to know